# Why is the terminology of labels and levels in factors so weird?

Tags: r, levels, factors

An example of a non-settable function would be `labels`. You can only set factor labels when they are created with the `factor()` function. There is no `labels<-` function. Not that 'labels' and 'levels' in factors make any sense....

```
>  fac <- factor(1:3, labels=c("one", "two", "three"))
> fac
[1] one   two   three
Levels: one two three
> labels(fac)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

OK, I asked for labels, which one might assume were as set by the factor call, but I get something quite ... what's the word, unintuitive?

```
> levels(fac)
[1] "one"   "two"   "three"
```

So it appears that setting labels is really setting levels.

```
>  fac <- factor(1:3, levels=c("one", "two", "three"))
> levels(fac)
[1] "one"   "two"   "three"
```

OK that is as expected. So what are labels when one sets levels?

```
>  fac <- factor(1:3, levels=c("one", "two", "three"), labels=c("x","y", "z") )
> labels(fac)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
> levels(fac)
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

It would seem that 'labels' arguments for `factor()` trump any 'levels' arguments for the specification of levels. Why should this be? And why does `labels()` return what I would have imagined to be retrieved with `as.character(as.numeric(fac))`?

(This was a tangential comment [labelled as such] in an earlier answer about assignment functions to which I was asked to move to a question. So here's your opportunity to enlighten me.)

Comment: Note that in both your second and third examples, `fac` or `str(fac)` would reveal that your factor is all `NA`s, because the `levels` specification you gave didn't match the values of `x` ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the way to think about the difference between `labels` and `levels` (ignoring the `labels()` function that Tommy describes in his answer) is that `levels` is intended to tell R which values to look for in the input (`x`) and what order to use in the levels of the resulting `factor` object, and `labels` is to change the *values* of the levels after the input has been coded as a factor ... as suggested by Tommy's answer, there is no part of the `factor` object returned by `factor()` that is called `labels` ... just the levels, which have been adjusted by the `labels` argument ... (clear as mud).

For example:

```
> f <- factor(x=c("a","b","c"),levels=c("c","d","e"))
> f
[1] <NA> <NA> c  
Levels: c d e
> str(f)
Factor w/ 3 levels "c","d","e": NA NA 1
```

Because the first two elements of `x` were not found in `levels`, the first two elements of `f` are `NA`. Because `"d"` and `"e"` were included in `levels`, they show up in the levels of `f` even though they did not occur in `x`.

Now with `labels`:

```
> f <- factor(c("a","b","c"),levels=c("c","d","e"),labels=c("C","D","E"))
> f
[1] <NA> <NA> C   
Levels: C D E
```

After R figures out what should be in the factor, it re-codes the levels.  One can of course use this to do brain-frying things such as:

```
> f <- factor(c("a","b","c"),levels=c("c","d","e"),labels=c("a","b","c"))
> f
[1] <NA> <NA> a   
Levels: a b c
```

Another way to think about `levels` is that `factor(x,levels=L1,labels=L2)` is equivalent to

```
f <- factor(x,levels=L1)
levels(f) <- L2
```

I think an appropriately phrased version of this example might be nice for Pat Burns's [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) -- there are plenty of factor puzzles in section 8.2, but not this particular one ...

Comment: You sound more sympathetic to my take that this is as 'clear as mud'. I do not understand the phrase " `levels` is intended to tell R which levels to look for in the input (x) ". Nor is there any function `labels<-` that would as you say "change the names of the levels after the input has been coded". They aren't names (in the R sense), anyway. They are values in an attribute.

Comment: I agree that the terminology is confusing. Does my updated answer help?

Comment: It does. Especially the clarification about input and output. Kind of like <gasp> SAS's informat and format.

Comment: Could we say (in a SPSS-like terminology): _Levels_ are the possible/acaptable/valid values. And _Labels_ are the _Value Labels_? e.g. A liktert scale from 0 to 4: `levels=0:4` and value lables: `labels=c("yes", "maybe yes", "maybe no", "no")`

Answer (score 17):

The `labels` function sounds like the perfect fit for getting the labels of a factor.

...but the `labels` function has nothing to do with factors! It is used as a generic way of getting something to "label" an object. For atomic vectors, this would be the names. But if there are no names, the `labels` function returns the element indices coerced to strings - something like `as.character(seq_along(x))`.

...So that's what your seeing when you try labels on a factor. The factor is an integer vector without any names, but with a `levels` attribute.

A factor has no labels. It only has levels. The `labels` argument to `factor` is just a way to be able to give a set of strings but produce another set of strings as the levels...
But to confuse things further, the `dput` function prints the `levels` attributes as `.Label`! I think that is a legacy thing...

```
# Translate lower case letters to upper case.
f <- factor(letters[2:4], letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:3])
dput(f)
#structure(c(2L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")
attributes(f)
#$levels
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
#
#$class
#[1] "factor"
```

However, since `labels` is a generic function, it would probably be a good idea to define `labels.factor` as follows (currently there is none). Perhaps something for R core to consider?

```
labels.factor <- function(x, ...) as.character(x)
```

Comment: Almost, with one small correction.  If there are no names, `labels` returns **sequence numbers** (`seq_along(x)`) coerced to strings ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker, Yep your're right - I shouldn't try stuff like `labels(1:3)` :-). I updated the answer.

Comment: Three problems with that answer. (1) With factors, `labels` does _not_ return what one would get with as.character(fac) which is how I would have interpreted your statement "returns values coerced to strings". (2) Can you explain why the `labels` function does not return what was set by the "labels" argument to `factor`? (3) And why 'labels' trumps 'levels'?

Comment: @Dwin (2) probably because `labels` is not designed for extracting the labels of factors.

Comment: @Dwin (1) the answer is now corrected; (3) see my comment to your question above, and my answer below.  I don't think `labels` and `levels` work the way you think they do  ...

Comment: I just noticed that in the `dput` output, the levels are referred to as `.Label` ... ouch!

Comment: I don't think that the `labels.factor` suggestion makes sense, because `?labels` says "Find a suitable set of labels from an object for use in printing or plotting, for example" -- so one would want `length(labels(f))==length(f)` ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker `.Label` appears only after `dput`. see unclass(fac). And if you assign the result of `dput`, then you cannot find `.Label`.