# Set levels for not existing values in R

Tags: r

First of all: I am not sure if this is the correct approach for my scenario.

There is a questionairy with 4 possible checkmarks ("A", "B", "C", "D") coded in the original data from `0` to `3`.. Imagine they are as age groups (under 30, 31 to 50, ...). No I want to have something like *value lables* (like SPSS offers) to use them later in summary tables or plots. In my understanding `R` offers the *levels* for this.

**The problem** now is that currently the `"A"` (coded as `0`) currently not exist in the data. But this can change in the future because the data is not fixed yet.

How can I set a *level* (SPSS meaning: value label) for a value (`0` in this example) that currently not exist in the data?

```
> set.seed(100)
> s <- sample(c(seq(1,3), NA), 10, replace=TRUE)
> f <- factor(s)
> f
 [1] 2    2    3    1    2    2    <NA> 2    3    1   
Levels: 1 2 3
> levels(f) <- c("A", # = 0
+                "B", # = 1
+                "C", # = 2
+                "D") # = 3
> f
 [1] B    B    C    A    B    B    <NA> B    C    A   
Levels: A B C D
```

Comment: see last example in `?levels`

Comment: @eddi I don't understand that example.

Comment: What's there to not understand - it's the exact problem you're trying to solve... `levels(f) = list(A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3)`

Comment: Try `f <- factor(s, levels = 0:3, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))`

Comment: Relavant reading: [Confusion between factor levels and factor labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869539/confusion-between-factor-levels-and-factor-labels); [Why is the terminology of labels and levels in factors so weird?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128413/why-is-the-terminology-of-labels-and-levels-in-factors-so-weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two difficulties. The numbering of factor-values starts with 1 as does almost all indexing in R and assignment to a non-existent level is not accepted so you could build in a "D" level at the time of the factor creations and then assignment to NA values could succeed:

```
 set.seed(100)
 s <- sample(c(seq(1,3), NA), 10, replace=TRUE)
 (f <- factor(s, levels=1:4,labels=LETTERS[1:4]))
# [1] B    B    C    A    B    B    <NA> B    C    A   
#Levels: A B C D
 f[ is.na(f) ] <- "D"
 f
 #[1] B B C A B B D B C A
#Levels: A B C D
```

I find working with character vectors to be far easier and suggest adopting a policy of using stringsAsFactors=FALSE for all your `read.*` operations.