# rename levels in ggplot because they are too long

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the factor names because they appear too long on the plot.

Codes:

```
levels(class_survey) <- list(None = "None.", Very_Little = "Very little. I've just dipped my toe in.",
                             Bit = "A bit. I've used coding in a limited capacity, such as for a small",
                             Some = "Some. I've had to write code for one or two classes and am co",
                             Good_Deal = "A good deal. I have several years of experience writing code.")
```

and I"m trying to make them appear in my actual plot, but I can't figure out how.

```
ggplot(class_survey, aes(x = Coding_Exp_Words, y = Coding_Exp_Scale)) + geom_jitter()
```

`Coding_Exp_words` is the data column whose label names I'm trying to change their label names.
.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this.

```r
class_survey_info <-  c(None = "None.", Very_Little = "Very little. I've just dipped my toe in.",
                        Bit = "A bit. I've used coding in a limited capacity, such as for a small",
                        Some = "Some. I've had to write code for one or two classes and am co",
                        Good_Deal = "A good deal. I have several years of experience writing code.")
```

(This information might as well be in a named character vector as in a list ...)

1. Use `factor()` with `levels` set equal to your original levels and `labels` as your short versions (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128413/why-is-the-terminology-of-labels-and-levels-in-factors-so-weird/7128515#7128515)).

```r
class_survey <- (class_survey
   |> mutate(across(Coding_Exp_Words, factor, levels = class_survey_info,
                    labels = names(class_survey_info)))
)
ggplot(...)
```

2. Use `forcats::recode()` (`mutate(across(Coding_Exp_Words, ~forcats::recode(., !!!class_survey_info)` )
3. Specify `breaks` and `values` in your x-axis scale.

```r
ggplot(...) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = class_survey_info, labels = names(class_survey_info))
```

(haven't tested because no reproducible example).

Solutions #1 and #2 can be done either in tidyverse with regular pipes (`|>` or `%>%`), or with `magrittr`'s assignment pipe (`class_survey %<>% mutate(...)`), or in base R  (`class_survey <- transform(class_survey, Coding_Exp_Words = factor(...))` or `class_survey$Coding_Exp_Words <- factor(class_survey$Coding_Exp_Words, ...)`)